# Optional value for MVC Route in beginning of Url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I'm trying to get these routes to work together but I am not sure how to get it working:

```
"{prcode}/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
"{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

The idea on my controllers is that if prcode is supplied it will use that product code, if not it will use a product code base on some other logic.

But for other controllers not concerned about a prcode it should just ignore it.

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add route constraint to limit the possible values valid for prcode. If the pattern is not matched for a given request it will try the second route.

Route constraints can be specified by a regular expression like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Product",
    "{prcode}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller="Home", action="Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { prcode = @"\d+" } // route constraint accepting only numbers for prcode
);
```

If you need more complex logic or maybe some values from the database you can create a custom constraint to achieve this. More on this here: http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but you need to change the way Route is declared,

```
"{prcode}/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
"{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

Since prcode may or may not have a value,(that is "prcode is optional"), you can not declare in as the first value,It should be like

```
"{controller}/{action}/{prcode}"
```

and prcode can be marked as `UrlParameter.Optional`

Comment: That does not answer the question, the question is specifically for beginning of the url?

Comment: Then you must not set prcode,controller,action as optional or any default value.If prcode is there the first route will identify it and if prcode is not there second route will identify it and prcode will be null